# How to display Vietnamese output with NetBeans 18 and JDK 20

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, utf-8, ide

I used to be able to display UTF-8 encoding before my last windows reinstallation then I re-downloaded NetBeans and JDK (the version is specified on the title), suppose that I have these pieces of code in main method in a maven project:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Đây là một văn bản Tiếng Việt");
}
```

I am expecting the output to display exactly like what I put in the println method.

I tried:

- Putting the `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` inside the `netbeans_default_options` of `netbeans.conf` file.
- Downgrade the JDK version to lower version (JDK-17).
- I also tried other font styles (Consolas, Arial, etc...) in NetBeans (both **Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Font**  and **Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Font**)

But they seem not working. Do I have to download any other font style or anything else?

Thanks for spending time to reply.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing the output in your CLI, wright? So maybe you are using a CLI code page which does not support outputing Vietnamese characters?

Comment: Hello @gthanop, I am seeing it on the console of NetBeans, it used to be able to displaying Vietnamese.

Comment: In case you are certain that the files are saved in UTF-8 format then the last thing I can think of is to give the compiler [the --encoding option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-encoding). Maybe you should test your code without any IDE and see if it works, in order to better determine where the problem lies (eg on the IDE console, on the file encoding, on the compiler encoding, other, etc).

Comment: I tried compile it on Terminal and PowerShell and got the unwanted ouput too.

Answer (score 0):

So I apparently figured it out by myself. After putting the `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` inside the `netbeans_default_options` of `netbeans.conf` file, I have to change the `system locale` I recommend **saving your progress** before following these steps because **it requires a system reboot**:

1. Open Run dialog by pressing `Win + R`
   [image: Run]
2. Type `intl.cpl`, press enter to open `Region` dialog
   [image: Region]
3. Switch to `Administrative` tab and press `Change system locale`
   [image: Change system locale]
4. Check on `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`
   [image: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support]
5. Press OK then restart your device.

This is also the way to make Windows Command Prompt to display in UTF-8 encoding, you can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/17684402)

Comment: Well done for putting in the work to show the answer. Had to laugh at ***Beta**: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support*

Comment: @g00se yes, I didn't know that exists

Comment: What version of Windows is that out of interest?

Comment: @g00se it's Window 10 22H2 Single Language, so sorry for my late reply.
Btw, how can I mention your name in my commnent, I'm quite new to the platform.

Comment: Ah I see. The name thing? I think you're doing it right already - I'm quite new myself ;)

Comment: @g00se because it doesn't view any hyperlink to your profile so I don't think I'm doing this right, thank you anyway

Comment: I assume it's a Javascript thing. Sometimes it's slow and occasionally doesn't appear at all